# jQuery change background/css class onclick of image clicked and others

Tags: jquery, html

I have a question regarding jQuery. I have multiple images that are, in essence, the same. The difference is that one of the images (let's call it the 'active' image) is a used as a side navigation bar which triggers "animated collapse" of the multiple DIVs in the Div to the right.  For this item which is clicked (and triggers the animated collapse) I am wanting to change the background image which has been defined in CSS.

I'd love it if I could get the "active" background/class to be displayed on the one, while the "inactive" icons revert to the "inactive status" onclick. As you select different items in the nav bar, each one changes it's background/class to the active designation, along with triggering the animated collapse effect.

Right now only the animatedcollapse event works, though the inactive status

Here's the HTML that I'm working with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="animatedcollapse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
animatedcollapse.addDiv('one', 'fade=1,speed=400,group=content,hide=0')
animatedcollapse.addDiv('two', 'fade=1,speed=400,group=content,hide=1')
animatedcollapse.addDiv('three', 'fade=1,speed=400,group=content,hide=1')
animatedcollapse.init()
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a.toggle').click(function () {
  $('a.toggle.select').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
a.toggle {
    background-image: url(images/contentnav_inactive.png);
    width: 275px;
    height: 41px;
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
a.toggle.active {
    background-image: url(images/contentnav_active.png);
    width: 275px;
    height: 41px;
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
a.contentheader {
    height: 25px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
        <div class="contentnav">
        <a class="contentheader" href="javascript:animatedcollapse.toggle('one')" id="toggle1_TGLink"><img src="images/contnav_header_business.png" width="252" height="25" style="margin: 2px 4px" /></a>
        <a class="toggle" id="toggle2_TGLink" href="javascript:animatedcollapse.toggle('two')"><img src="images/contentnav_text_busauto.png" width="269" height="41" /></a>
        <a class="toggle" href="javascript:animatedcollapse.toggle('three')" id="toggle3_TGLink" ><img src="images/contentnav_text_bop.png" width="269" height="41" /></a>
</div>
      <div class="toggle></div>
      <div class="contenttext">
            <div id="one" class="TG_hidden"><h1>Business Insurance Overview</h1>
                <hr />
       </div>
            <div id="two" class="TG_hidden"><h1>Business Auto</h1>
                <hr />

            </div>
            <div id="three" class="TG_hidden"><h1>Business Owners Insurance (BOP)</h1>
            <hr />

        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @maxedison Sorry, for not specifying.  The CSS class won't change onclick, rather it just stays as "a.toggle" and won't change to "a.toggle.active", all else works (animated collapse,etc.).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
$('a.toggle').click(function () {
    $('a.toggle').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

I've just removed `.select` class

"animatedcollapse.js" line 107, you should remove "@"  so this line should have been

`var $allcontrols = $('[rel^="collapse-"], [rel^="expand-"], [rel^="toggle-"]')`

also you should wrap your selector in `$(document).ready` as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.toggle').click(function () {
        alert("active");
        $('a.toggle').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it and it's still not causing any effect.  You can see it in the live environment here: http://mlminsure.com/test/businesscontent.php.  No content added yet.

Comment: Then you've got some other problem. Mehdi's code should work fine.